# ng-grid afterSelectionChange return value

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

it's possible to afterSelectionChange return value with ng-grid ???

how can I accomplish it?  I want to get $scope.programEdit value,

setPagingData function to set data show on view ,

getPagedDataAsync function to get value with $resource

anyone ideas ?

please help

```
$scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize, type){
    var array = [];
    for(var key in data){
      if(!data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        continue;
      }
        array.push(key, data[key])
    }
    if(type == 0){
      var a = array.slice(1,4);
      $scope.myData = a[0];
    }else{
      var a = array.slice(1);
      $scope.myData = a;
    }

    $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    return $scope.myData
};


$scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText, type) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var data;
          programService.query({
             page: page
          }, function (result) {
            data = {
              'program': result
            };
            $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize,0)
            return data
          });
    }, 100);

};

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
    totalServerItems:'totalServerItems',
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
    selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
    multiSelect: false,
    afterSelectionChange: function ($routeParams, $location, programService) {
      $scope.program = $scope.mySelections[0];
      var id = $scope.mySelections[0].programId;
      if ($scope.mySelections[0].programId) {
        $scope.programEdit = {
          'program': programService.get({
            page: 1, 
            id: $scope.mySelections[0].programId
          })};
      }


    }
};
```

I want to get it to show on edit html

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
 <input type="hidden" ng-model="programEdit.programId"/>
 <dl> 
  <dt>Program Name</dt>
   <dd><input name="programName" type="text" ng-model="programEdit.programName"/></dd>
  </dl>
  <div class="form-actions">
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to provide more details, what is organization of pages. Which page defines the first scope, how is edit page loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.programEdit` should contain `programId` and `programName` (something like `$scope.programEdit = {programId: 11, programName: 'Hello'}` but what you do is setting `programService.get` to a property named program.

What you should do, assuming that programService.get is a promise, and that it returns a JSON object with the data then you should do something like that:

```
programService.get({ page: 1, id: $scope.mySelections[0].programId }).success(function(data) {
  $scope.programEdit = {programName: data.programName, programId: data.programId};
});
```

Comment: yes, programService.get is return a JSON object , I hope use $resource to get value not $http